# Bathroom caulking question

Tags: bathtub, trim, caulk

Just curious if anything in the posted picture should give alarm before recaulking (further prep is underway).  Is there supposed to be a deep crevice between the molding and the adjacent tile?  Can you just recaulk over?  [image]

Comment: You'd should clean that joint out before re-caulking it, rather than re-caulking "over" that mess. As with paint, preparation is 90% of the job and also 90% of the success of the job.

Comment: Agree with Ecnerwal. Use a razor knife and remove ALL caulking along the tub base. Clean residue with a solvent like [goof off](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/300/13/1372ea4f-4f17-476b-8ee3-c9bd664baf82_300.jpg) afterwards, wiping down area with plain water before applying silicone caulking for wet areas.

Comment: The gap is normal. The trim tile is to cover it.

Comment: I have never meet a tile person that can get them all perfectly straight and level, so a gap is normal, for that and expansion reasons.  But third that clean and caulk.